# Tom Apostol number theory problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or give a counter example to the following problem:

Given integers $a, b, c, d$ such that

$ad - bc  \equiv 1  \pmod n$.

Show that there exist integers $A, B, C, D$ such that

$AD - BC = 1$

and

$A  \equiv  a  \pmod n$,

$B  \equiv  b  \pmod n$,

$C  \equiv  c  \pmod n$,

$D  \equiv  d  \pmod n$.

Solution:

Theorem:   If  a  and  b  are natural numbers, then there exist integers  u  and  v such that
gcd(a, b)  =  ua + vb.

Let  n  be a strictly positive integer.

Given integers  a, b, c, d  such that  ad – bc  is congruent to  1  (mod n).

ad – bc  is congruent to  1  (mod n)  has an integer solution a, b, c, d

<=>  n  divides (ad – bc – 1)

<=>  there exist integers  k, a, b, c, d  such that  ad – bc - 1  =  kn

<=>  there exist integers  k, a, b, c, d  such that  ad – bc – kn  =  1

<=>  there is a linear combination of  integers  a, c, n  that equals  1

<=>  gcd(a, c, n)  =  1

<=>  there is a linear combination of  integers  b, d, n  that equals  1

<=>  gcd(b, d, n)  =  1

The hypothesis: ad – bc  is congruent to 1 (mod n).

is equivalent to gcd(a, c, n)  =  1  and  gcd(b, d, n)  =  1

Given integers  n >= 3,  a  =  1,  b  =  1,  c  =  n – 2,  d  =  n - 1

ad  -  bc  = (1)(n - 1)  -  (1)(n -2)  =  1

ad  -  bc  is congruent to  1  (mod n)

gcd(a, c, n)  =  gcd(1, n – 2, n)  =  1

gcd(b, d, n)  =  gcd(1, n – 1, n)  =  1

Let  A  =  1,  B  =  1,  C  =  2n – 2,  D  = 2n - 1

AD  -  BC  =  (1)(2n - 1)  -  (1)(2n - 2)  =  1

A  =  1  is congruent to  1  (mod n)

B  =  1  is congruent to  1  (mod n)

C  =  2n - 2  is congruent to  n - 2  (mod n)

D  =  2n - 1  is congruent to  n - 1  (mod n)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{gcd}{\operatorname{gcd}}$
Let me give an elementary method to reduce to the case $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. This will complement @Misha’s answer.

We may assume that $a,b\neq 0$. Write $u = \gcd(a,b)$ so that $a = a'u$ and $b = b'u$, where $\gcd(a',b') = 1$. Notice that $\gcd(a,b,n) = 1$ implies $\gcd(u,n) = 1$. Let $a''$ be the largest divisor of $a'$ with $\gcd(a'',u) = 1$.

*Claim:* Setting $b_0:= b + a''n$, we have $\gcd(a,b_0) = 1$.
Recall that we have
$$
a = a'u\qquad \text{and}\qquad b_0 = b'u + a''n.
$$
We show that no (prime) divisor of $a$ divides $b_0$. First, let $p$ be a divisor of $u$. Because of $\gcd(u,n) = \gcd(u,a'') = 1$, it follows that $p$ does not divide $b_0$. If $p$ divides $a'$, but not $u$, then $p$ divides $a''$. But $\gcd(a',b') = 1$ shows that $p$ does not divide $b'$ and hence it does not divide $b_0$. Hence $\gcd(a,b_0) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We begin by reducing to the case $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Certainly at least $\gcd(a,b,n)=1$, because $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $ad-bc$, which is $1 \bmod n$. By Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions, there is a prime of the form $\frac{a + kn}{\gcd(a,n)}$ larger than $b$, so $\gcd(\frac{a + kn}{\gcd(a,n)},b)=1$, and therefore $\gcd(a+kn,b) = 1$. Replacing $a$ by $a+kn$ does not change the fact that $ad-bc \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

*(Note: this was probably overkill, but it's late at night, and I wanted to get to the good part.)*

Let $m$ be such that $ad-bc = mn + 1$. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, the equation $ax + by = -m$ has an integer solution $(x,y)$. Now set $A = a$, $B = b$, $C = c - ny$, $D = d + nx$, and observe that
$$AD - BC = a(d+nx) - b(c-ny) = ad - bc + n(ax + by) = ad - bc - mn = 1.$$

---

Some general notes on the problem: we may think of it as finding values $h,j,k,l$ such that
$$\det\left( \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d\end{bmatrix} + n\begin{bmatrix}h & j \\ k & l\end{bmatrix}\right)  = 1 \tag{1}$$
given that $$\det \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d\end{bmatrix} \equiv 1 \pmod n.$$ In the special case where $$\det \begin{bmatrix}h & j \\ k & l\end{bmatrix} = 0,$$ the determinant in $(1)$ updates according to reasonable rules. My solution by assuming $\gcd(a,b)=1$ was able to make use of a particularly simple singular matrix: the one where $h=j=0$. But it's probably possible to avoid the annoying work of getting to that assumption by being more flexible in the choice of this matrix.